# androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError

Tags: android, android-espresso

I got following error info when i run my unit test.

```
androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'is selected <false>' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: is selected <false>
Got: "AppCompatImageView{id=2131296490, res-name=image_view_play, visibility=VISIBLE, width=131, height=131, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=true, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@e4cb265, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=435.0, y=0.0}"

at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1736)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:16)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:36)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:103)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:31)
at com.zhixin.wedeep.homepage.ui.TestAudioViewActivity.testAllDataInitial(TestAudioViewActivity.kt:73)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
```

This error hanppened in this line:      `onView(withId(R.id.image_view_play)).check(matches(isNotSelected()))`

**'is selected `<false>`' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: is selected `<false>`**     It's truly weird.

Added: I got another strange error when run my unit test, similar with above one.

```
androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'with text: is "11:00"' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: with text: is "11:00"
Got: "AppCompatTextView{id=2131296768, res-name=text_view_total_time, visibility=INVISIBLE, width=0, height=43, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams@4c3a3c6, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=1041.0, y=1269.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"
```

Who has ideas for this problem?

This is my test function.

```
  @Test
    fun testAllDataInitial() {
        val c = GSON.fromJson( Util.getFileString("composition.json"),Composition::class.java)


        onView(withId(R.id.image_view_vote)).check(matches(isNotSelected()))
        onView(withId(R.id.text_view_vote_number)).check(matches(withText(c.likeAmount)))
        onView(withId(R.id.image_view_play)).check(matches(isNotSelected()))
        onView(withId(R.id.text_view_total_time)).check(matches(withText(c.formattedDuration)))
        onView(withId(R.id.text_view_author)).check(matches(withText("-${c.author}-"))).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
        onView(withId(R.id.text_view_type)).check(matches(withText(c.remark))).check(matches(withEffectiveVisibility(Visibility.GONE)))
        onView(withId(R.id.text_view_description)).check(matches(withText(c.author))).check(matches(withEffectiveVisibility(Visibility.GONE)))
    }
```

Setup function:

```
 @Before
    fun init() {
        hiltRule.inject()
        Util.RETROFIT
        enqueueResponse("composition.json")
        UserInfoManager.instance.putIs4gNetwork(true)
        scenario = launchActivity(intent)
        dataBindingIdlingResourceRul = DataBindingIdlingResourceRule(scenario)
        dataBindingIdlingResourceRul.starting(null)
        scenario.onActivity {
            IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(it.mIdleResource)
        }
        onView(withId(R.id.btnOpen)).perform(click())
    }
```

Comment: If you think your tests are written correctly, then it's very like that they fail due to asynchronous interaction. Do you use asynchronous methods to update your views like using a `Handler.post`?

Comment: @Aaron  I have post more details about my test. The first two lines work correctly, so i think all data has initialised

Comment: Your test looks fine, but it feels like the test might be having race condition issue. Does your test pass if you put `Thread.sleep()` for a few seconds in the first line of `testAllDataInitial()`?

Comment: @Aaron I have worked out. The problem is that requiured data and result data are mismatch. But espresso prompt is not clear.